# io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException$CompositeExceptionCausalChain: Chain of Causes for CompositeException In Order Received

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, micronaut, reactivex

Custom global exception in micronaut

```
public class GlobalException extends RuntimeException{
}

@Produces
@Singleton
@Requires(classes = {GlobalException.class, ExceptionHandler.class})
public class GlobalExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler<GlobalException, HttpResponse> {

    @Override
    public HttpResponse handle(HttpRequest request, GlobalException exception) {
        return HttpResponse.ok(0);
    }
}
```

Throwing an exception from the reactive java not working, the exception must be caught by the global handler.

```
Maybe<FindProductCommand> find(ProductSearchCriteriaCommand searchCriteria);

 public Maybe<FindProductCommand> get(ProductSearchCriteriaCommand searchCriteria) {
        return iProductManager.find(searchCriteria)
                .doOnError(throwable ->  { throw new GlobalException(); });
    }
```

CompositeException is usually thrown when your error handler itself throws an exception when it's handling an error thrown in the stream, But I need to throw an exception from the error handler

```
    io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred. 
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeOnErrorReturn$OnErrorReturnMaybeObserver.onError(MaybeOnErrorReturn.java:88)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedMaybeObserver.onError(RxInstrumentedMaybeObserver.java:58)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableElementAtMaybe$ElementAtSubscriber.onError(FlowableElementAtMaybe.java:94)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onError(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableOnErrorNext$OnErrorNextSubscriber.onError(FlowableOnErrorNext.java:90)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onError(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscriptions.EmptySubscription.error(EmptySubscription.java:55)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableError.subscribeActual(FlowableError.java:40)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:57)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableOnErrorNext$OnErrorNextSubscriber.onError(FlowableOnErrorNext.java:115)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onError(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeToFlowable$MaybeToFlowableSubscriber.onError(MaybeToFlowable.java:75)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedMaybeObserver.onError(RxInstrumentedMaybeObserver.java:58)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableElementAtMaybe$ElementAtSubscriber.onError(FlowableElementAtMaybe.java:94)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onError(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onError(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:102)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onError(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate(FlowableFlatMap.java:567)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.drainLoop(FlowableFlatMap.java:374)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.drain(FlowableFlatMap.java:366)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onError(FlowableFlatMap.java:325)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onError(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableTimeoutTimed$TimeoutSubscriber.onTimeout(FlowableTimeoutTimed.java:139)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableTimeoutTimed$TimeoutTask.run(FlowableTimeoutTimed.java:170)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException$CompositeExceptionCausalChain: Chain of Causes for CompositeException In Order Received =>
    at io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException.getCause(CompositeException.java:110)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:57)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:119)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.error(Logger.java:538)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.logException(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:2162)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.writeDefaultErrorResponse(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:2139)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.exceptionCaughtInternal(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:426)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.access$200(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:151)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler$5.doOnError(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1408)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onError(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:63)
    at io.reactivex.internal.util.HalfSerializer.onError(HalfSerializer.java:70)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.StrictSubscriber.onError(StrictSubscriber.java:103)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onError(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onError(FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.java:64)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onError(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:66)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler$7.doOnError(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1580)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onError(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:63)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.Publishers$2.doOnError(Publishers.java:270)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onError(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:63)
    at io.reactivex.internal.util.HalfSerializer.onError(HalfSerializer.java:70)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.StrictSubscriber.onError(StrictSubscriber.java:103)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onError(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeToFlowable$MaybeToFlowableSubscriber.onError(MaybeToFlowable.java:75)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedMaybeObserver.onError(RxInstrumentedMaybeObserver.java:58)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The source did not signal an event for 10000000000 nanoseconds and has been terminated.
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: fete.bird.common.extension.GlobalException: null
    at fete.bird.api.v1.controller.ProductController.lambda$get$0(ProductController.java:44)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeOnErrorReturn$OnErrorReturnMaybeObserver.onError(MaybeOnErrorReturn.java:85)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedMaybeObserver.onError(RxInstrumentedMaybeObserver.java:58)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableElementAtMaybe$ElementAtSubscriber.onError(FlowableElementAtMaybe.java:94)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onError(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableOnErrorNext$OnErrorNextSubscriber.onError(FlowableOnErrorNext.java:90)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onError(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscriptions.EmptySubscription.error(EmptySubscription.java:55)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableError.subscribeActual(FlowableError.java:40)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:57)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableOnErrorNext$OnErrorNextSubscriber.onError(FlowableOnErrorNext.java:115)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onError(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeToFlowable$MaybeToFlowableSubscriber.onError(MaybeToFlowable.java:75)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedMaybeObserver.onError(RxInstrumentedMaybeObserver.java:58)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableElementAtMaybe$ElementAtSubscriber.onError(FlowableElementAtMaybe.java:94)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onError(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onError(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:102)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onError(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate(FlowableFlatMap.java:567)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.drainLoop(FlowableFlatMap.java:374)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.drain(FlowableFlatMap.java:366)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onError(FlowableFlatMap.java:325)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onError(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:66)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I recommend to file an issue at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues so the Micronaut core team can verify this. In addition you can provide a sample Micronaut app with the issue that reproduces the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual exception thrown is a `CompositeException`, so that is why it doesn't match `ExceptionHandler<GlobalException, HttpResponse>`. Micronaut doesn't have special handling for `CompositeException` and even if it did, I don't think a sensible default exists because there are multiple exceptions but only 1 exception handler should be called.

In general you should never do `.doOnError(throwable ->  { throw new GlobalException(); });`. Instead you can use `onErrorResumeNext` and return a new publisher that can potentially emit an error. If it emits an error that error will be received instead of a `CompositeException`.

Comment: An example for return a new publisher that can potentially emit an error will be most helpful

Comment: return iProductManager.find(searchCriteria)
                .onErrorResumeNext(throwable ->  { return Maybe.error(new GlobalException(throwable));}); works for me